# phpSlim twg-view not working

Tags: php, slim

i am getting error in my slim framework application. i don't know why twig-view is not working. twig-view is downloaded in vendor directory.
this is my index file

```
<?php
require  __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Settings
$config = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
        'addContentLengthHeader' => false,
    ],
];

$app = new \Slim\App($config);

// Get container
$container = $app->getContainer();

// Register component on container
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig( __DIR__ . '/resources/views', [
        'cache' => false
    ]);

    // Instantiate and add Slim specific extension

    $view->addExtension(new Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
    $container['router'],
    $container['request']->getUri()

    ));

    return $view;
};

// Home
$app->get('/home','index');



function index($request, $response, $args)
{
   return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig'); // here is the error 
}

$app->run();
```

i am getting error om $this keyword
error details

```
Details

Type: Error
Message: Using $this when not in object context
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\slim\api\index.php
Line: 42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use this when you do not have a closure

> If you use a Closure instance as the route callback, the closure’s state is bound to the Container instance. This means you will have access to the DI container instance inside of the Closure via the `$this` keyword.

(Reference: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html)

You can separate it when you assign the closure to a variable

```
$indexRoute = function ($request, $response, $args)
{
    return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig'); // here is the error 
}

$app->get('/home', $indexRoute);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring route incorectly, try

```
// This callback will process GET request to /index URL    
$app->get('/index', function($request, $response, $args) {
    return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig');
});
```

Instead of declaring a function, you should call `$app` method to register a route.

EDIT

It is also possible to "separate" route declaration from the callback. You can create separate classes (a-la controllers in MVC pattern), like this:

```
// Declaring a controller class with __invoke method, so it acts as a function
class MyController
{

    public function __invoke($request, $resposne)
    {
        // process a request, return response
    }

}

// And here's how you add it to the route
$app->get('/index', 'MyController');
```

I suggest you read the [appropriate section of the documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#container-resolution). It's dead simple.

Comment: that declaration worked for me when i returned a response without using view. is it possible to separate route and callable ?

Comment: You can use traditional controllers, I've updated the answer and added a link to the documentation.